# UITableViewController paging detect top

Tags: xamarin.ios

Am busy with paging, i got it right to detect the bottom of the table using the code below but how can i detect the top ?

```
protected bool IsAtBottomOfTable() { 
var currentOffset =TableView.ContentOffset.Y;
var maximumOffset = TableView.ContentSize.Height -TableView.Frame.Size.Height;
return maximumOffset - currentOffset <= 10.00;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can i detect the top ?

When tableview scrolls to the top, its `ContentOffset.Y` will be 0.

#### Solution

We can override `Scrolled` method with `UIScrollViewDelegate`.

```
((UIScrollView)table).Delegate = new MyScrollViewDelegate();

public class MyScrollViewDelegate:UIScrollViewDelegate {
    public override void Scrolled(UIScrollView scrollView)
    {
        bool isTop = (scrollView.ContentOffset.Y <= 0);
    }
}
```